# What is meant when you pass in {} within the SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql

Can anyone decipher what is going on here?

As far as i can make out, I am updating a table called "shops" where the first id of the shops is equal to 1?  Am I right, can someone please give me a fuller explanation? How can shopId differ from SHOPID

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("UPDATE shops SET NumberOfWindows = {0} WHERE shopId ='{1}'", ShopDataCount, SHOPID), Connection)
```

Comment: Those are the arguments to `String.Format` - {0} will be replaced by the value in ShopDataCount and {1} will be replaced by the value in SHOPID. It's also a very bad way to make a statement for sql. It should be using parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks @Nikki9696 Can you correct to make a better query?

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet

Comment: @HansKeﬆing omg lol how did i not know this site was a thing...bobby tables  =)

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to with the the query itself, it will be replaced by `String.Format`, before it is passed the the database engine. It is a token that tells the String.Format operation, where to put the variable.
It inserts the value of `SHOPID` at this place.
By the way, this is **not a good way** to compose querys because it makes it vulnerable to **SQL injection**.
The preferred way are **parameterized queries** see for example:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx

Comment: The only thing about that article is that it says `AddWithValue` is the easiest way. Easiest maybe. Good? no.

Comment: Well, you can `Add` with a `Value`, just don't use `AddWithValue` to do it